# "import tkinter as tk" me tira error

Tags: python, python-3.7

No sé porqué no me deja crear una ventana ahora, antes si podía perfectamente
Ya me había pasado una vez pero se arregló solo, o será problema del programa? :(
O alomejor escribí algo mal?

Estoy usando el programa Spyder 5.0.2, Python 3.7.9

```
import tkinter as tk


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Traductor")
ventana.geometry('500x500')

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="Calcular")
boton.pack(padx=300,pady=250)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Me sale esto

File "C:\Users\leoja\Desktop\traduccion\ventanas.py", line 4, in 
v = tk.tk()

AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk'

ACTUALIZACION:

El problema se arreglo y ahora puedo hacerlo, pero no tengo idea de porqué habia pasado :/

Comment: Será `tk.Tk()`?

Comment: Prueba con tk.Tk (notese la segunda t en mayuscula). El primer tk es el modulo tkinter, el segundo tk es el objeto que representa a la ventana. Ese es el que tiene que tener mayuscula.

Comment: Quizá fue por que antes lo pusiste en minuscula

Comment: ahí me funcionó, pero igual ya lo habia probado antes y no me servía, no sé que onda :/

Comment: Que raro... Habrás puesto la mayúscula en el lugar equivocado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que es `TK()` en vez de `tk()`

```
v = tk.Tk() #Mayusculas
```

Comment: La segunda k va en minusculas. Solo aviso para ayudar. O sea, seria tk.Tk

Comment: si ahora me sirve, pero lo raro era que lo tenia así desde el principio y me saltó el error, pense que si lo ponia en miniscula serviria :/